# Spring REST validation

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have this REST API method

```
 @GetMapping
 public ResponseEntity doSome(@Valid DataTypeRequest dataType){}
```

and `ConstraintValidator` that validates `DataTypeRequest`.

Now I should implement HandlerMethodArgumentResolver for DataTypeRequest, so my REST API method will look like:

`@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity doSome(@Valid @DataTypeRequestAnnotation DataTypeRequest dataType){}`

And after this changes `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` works but ConstraintValidator doesn't. So how can I validate my entity after HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check parameter for `@Valid` and invoke `validate()` method.

```
if (parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(Valid.class){            
    binderFactory
        .createBinder(webRequest, resolvedObject, "resolvedObjectLogicalName")
        .validate ();
}
```